Autodesk aps-iot issue: heatmap failed, sprite is not bounding with rooms
I just start learning about the forge viewer, and currently trying to create data-visualization in forge viewer.
I cloned the Autodesk Data Visualization service, aps-iot-extensions-demo-master.
I followed previous similar question I solved this issue by setting
const APS_MODEL_VIEW = '' 

and changing
getDefaultGeometry() 

to
getDefaultGeometry(true).
I just replaced APS_CLIENT_ID, APS_CLIENT_SECRET, APS_MODEL_URN and APS_MODEL_VIEW; the URN and GUID.
I used the same model racbasicsampleproject.rvt, i couldn't find rooms in model structure with the below command:
const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(model);

Then I found a blog to get the rooms information from the revit file. I followed the instruction and create a job to generateMasterViews.
{
  "input": {
    "urn": "<<URN>>"
  },
  "output": {
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "svf",
        "views": [
          "2d",
          "3d"
        ],
        "advanced":{
          "generateMasterViews":true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

But, I'm still not getting the rooms in model structure.
However, the heatmap is not visualized in the Web and there is no error existing in the console.
How can I get the rooms structure from the revit model from racbasicsampleproject.rvt model?
How can I ensure that sprites are bound with the rooms?
How can I get bound of the rooms, so I can show heatmap?
I have not changed the sensor detail in io.moked.js.
{
    'sensor-1': {
        name: 'Living Room',
        description: 'Basic sensor in the middle of the living room.',
        groupName: 'Level 1',
        location: {
            x: 31.92,
            y: 11.49,
            z: -12.97
        },
        objectId: 4124
    },
    'sensor-2': {
        name: 'Dining Table',
        description: 'Basic sensor at the dining table.',
        groupName: 'Level 1',
        location: {
            x: -10,
            y: 41.64,
            z: -12.15
        },
        objectId: 4111
    },
    'sensor-3': {
        name: 'Kitchen',
        description: 'Basic sensor in the kitchen.',
        groupName: 'Level 1',
        location: {
            x: 10,
            y: 41.64,
            z: -12.15
        },
        objectId: 4111
    },
    'sensor-4': {
        name: 'Bedroom',
        description: 'Basic sensor in the bedroom.',
        groupName: 'Level 2',
        location: {
            x: -7.46,
            y: 41.47,
            z: 2.97
        },
        objectId: 4085
    }
};


Please create the master view of the revit model with the following api
Create job link detail
send x-ads-force = true in header
{
  "input": {
    "urn": "<<URN>>"
  },
  "output": {
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "svf",
        "views": [
          "2d",
          "3d"
        ],
        "advanced":{
          "generateMasterViews":true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

after that by using the following command to console the update floor map.
const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(model);
let levelRoomsMap = await structureInfo.getLevelRoomsMap();
console.log(levelRoomsMap)


Ali is right. If you're trying to re-translate a model (URN) that you already translated before, you'll need to include a "force" parameter.
